# regex preg_replace php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have random variable like:
Strip @ 489.000
Strip 1 @ 489.000
Strip 2 @ 589.000

I need output will be:
only number after 'anything @ ' 489.000

so give me output:
489.000
489.000
589.000

hot to achive this use php regex?

```
$string = '  Strip 1 @ 489.000'; $pattern = ' /(\s\S) @ (\d+)/i'; $replacement = '$3'; echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Use `preg_match_all('/\S\s@\s+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $text, $matches)` and `print_r($matches[0])`

Comment: that work. thanks but how to call that to single variable.. like $string=$matches[0] ;

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all matches, use

```
if (preg_match_all('/\S\s@\s+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

To get the first match, use

```
if (preg_match('/\S\s@\s+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $text, $match)) {
    print_r($match[0]);
}
```

**Details**

- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a dot and 1+ digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9Thcr/1).